# Extract paragraph number of word document using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been asked for assistance in getting the paragraph number of a comment in Word. Note, Word VBA is not my forte. Having done some searching I've butchered down an example for extracting the comments themselves, but unsure how to get the paragraph number.

In the example below, I want to extract the comment (which is inserted as a word comment) and the relevant paragraph number, i.e:

Comment 1 - 1.1.1.1

Comment 2 - 1.1.1.3

Comment 3 - 1.1.2.1.1

[image: Word Comment Example]
Sample code below. how do I access the paragraph level property, none of my attempts so far have yielded anything & I can't find it in the documentation.

```
Public Sub ExtractComments()

Dim oDoc As Document
Dim nCount As Long
Dim n As Long

Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
nCount = ActiveDocument.Comments.Count

'Get info from each comment from oDoc and insert in table
For n = 1 To nCount
Debug.Print (oDoc.Comments(n).Scope.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber))
Debug.Print (oDoc.Comments(n).Scope.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber))
Debug.Print (oDoc.Comments(n).Scope.ParagraphStyle)
Debug.Print (oDoc.Comments(n).Scope.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString)
Next n

Set oDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
Sub GetParagraphNumberofComment()
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 1 To ActiveDocument.Comments.Count
        MsgBox ActiveDocument.Range(0, ActiveDocument.Comments(n).Scope.Paragraphs(1).Range.End).Paragraphs.Count
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've just edited the formatting a little above to help make it clearer - the issue is finding the last paragraph header before the comment. Your sample gives me the line number of the comment, not the paragraph number of the header above if that makes sense?

Comment: So once you find the paragraph number of the comment, can you not just subtract 1 from the index to get the previous one? maybe i am not fully understanding.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69183801/extract-comments-from-multiple-word-docs-into-excel