# Counting the amount of comments in word with excel vba fails

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to get the amount of comments in a word document. When the word documents only have text and comments my code works.

But when I run the (excel vba) code over a word document which includes tables then I get the runtime error 91 "*Object variable or With block variable not set*".

I don't know if this information is needed: When there is a table in the word document, then there are also comments to text in the table...

How can I change my code that it runs for every word document?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Now my code:

```
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim document As Word.Document

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle4").Activate


Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")


' This word document just contains text and comments and with this document there is no runtime error 91
Set document = appWord.Documents.Open( _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Testfile_JustTextAndComments.docx")

' This word document contains tables, text and comments and with this document there arises a runtime error 91
'Set document = appWord.Documents.Open( _
'ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Testfile_TableTextAndComments.docx")


' Show the amount of comments in the word document
Range("A1") = document.Comments.Count ' when I click the debug-button of the runtime error 91 this line of code is marked (with Testfile_TableTextAndComments.docx)


document.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
appWord.Quit
Set document = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing
```

Comment: Seems to be a fail on opening the MS Word file. Check if it is really loaded on the variable 'document'

Comment: @ALeXceL: Hey, how do I check if the word file is loaded on the variable `document`? But btw: With the first file it works - can there really be a loading error?!

Comment: @jonsson: That seems to be the issue. The variable `document` is empty, so the word document is not opened. So what can I do to ensure that the document is opened?

Comment: 1) after 'opening' the docx, test the 'document' variable: If Not document Is Nothing Then 2) test this path for validity: ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Testfile_JustTextAndComments.docx

Comment: If the document e.g. is loaded from internet it might be opened in protected view. (--> yellow header) - then you can't access it by vba until it is unlocked.

Comment: @jonsson Thanks a lot for your hints. I have found a solution that works and I will post it soon.

Comment: @ALeXcel Thanks a lot for your hints. I have found a solution that works and I will post it soon.

Comment: @Ike Thanks a lot for your hint. I have found a solution that works and I will post it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the runtime error 91 *Object variable or With block variable not set* it was suggested to me to check if the variable `document` is empty (so thanks to all commenters for their contribution).

```
' check if word document is loaded on document
If document Is Nothing Then 
   MsgBox ("document not opened")
End If
```

And when I run in the error 91 then the `document` was empty.

Here in
[Extract comments from multiple word docs into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69183801/extract-comments-from-multiple-word-docs-into-excel)
I found a solution that works for me, so that the runtime error 91 was gone.

When opening the word file, I just have to add some arguments

```
Set dokument = appWord.Documents.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Testfile_TableTextAndComments.docx", AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
```

Here you can find some additional hints and explanation to the [Documents.Open method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open)

And now the whole code:

```
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim document As Word.Document

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle4").Activate


Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")


' This word document contains tables, text and comments and with the additional arguments the runtime error 91 doesn't appear anymore
Set document = appWord.Documents.Open( _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Testfile_TableTextAndComments.docx", _
AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)


' check if word document is loaded on document - but this code snippet isn't needed anymore
If document Is Nothing Then 
   MsgBox ("document not opened")
End If


' Show the amount of comments in the word document
Range("A1") = document.Comments.Count ' 


document.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
appWord.Quit
Set document = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing
```