# How to pass a string as a formula/ command in vba?

Tags: arrays, vba, string, ms-word

I am trying to populate comments from word document into a multidimensional array and to do that I populated another array with formulas as stings and passing those to the corresponding cells of the final array as shown below. **values** array has the formulas as strings. But when i pass it, vba is not reading them as formula but as stirings. So the array is getting populated with formulas instead of results based on that formulas. How can i solve this? Thanks in advance!

```
Sub extractCommets()
    
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim pageOffset As Integer
    Dim commentDf() As Variant
    Dim values(2) As Variant

    pageOffset = 10
    cnt = ActiveDocument.Comments.Count
    
    ReDim commentDf(0 To cnt, 0 To 2)
    
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    values(0) = "ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Scope.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) - pageOffset"
    values(1) = "ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Author"
    values(2) = "ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Range.Text"
    
    For i = LBound(commentDf, 1) To UBound(commentDf, 1)
        For j = LBound(commentDf, 2) To UBound(commentDf, 2)

            'passing string as formula
            commentDf(i, j) = values(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't execute text as code like that - a string is just a string.  Why not just put those 3 lines as code inside the `i` loop?

Comment: @TimWilliams previously that's what I did and it is working. but i wanted a more generalized solution so that's why i tried this approach. thank you.

Comment: to extract just about everything you might want to know about comments, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69183801/extract-comments-from-multiple-word-docs-into-excel